# Validate correct answer and add marks in PHP quiz

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, validation

I am working on a simple quiz web app and i want to validate each and every question on submit button showing the correct and add marks for right questions.

I have created my first question page like this

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cric Quiz </title>

    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/style.CSS" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    </head>
<body>

<div>
    <h1>Cric Quiz</h1>
</div>

<div id='quesNo'>
    <center>Question 01</center>
</div>

<div id='questions'>
    <center>When did Australia win their first ever world cup?</center>
</div>

<div id='answers'>
<input type="radio" name="year" value="1992">1992<br>
<input type="radio" name="year" value="1996">1996<br>
<input type="radio" name="year" value="2000">2000<br>
<input type="radio" name="year" value="2012">2012
</div>

<center><a href="<?=base_url().'index.php/Questions/question_2';?>" class="button1">Next</a></center>

</body>
</html>
```

My controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Questions extends CI_Controller {

public function question_1()
    {

        $this->load->view('quiz_one');

    }

    public function question_2()
    {

        $this->load->view('quiz_two');

    }
}
```

How to validate my answers in my controller

PS: I'm using codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. Just have one function and pass the question id to that. If tomorrow, you have 1000 questions, will you create as many functions??

First store the correct answer in database.

Next your html should have the forms, submit the form with post data

Post the question id in form post

Add this code in controller,

```
// run query to fetch data from database based on the question in
if($this->input->post("year") == "value from database"){

} else {

}
```